# Strange response text encoding from REST web application in Tomcat

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, encoding

I encountered a strange response text from my web application running in Tomcat. Basically my web app will envoke a ping application running in the command and the result will be returned to client.

The code is like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/pingport/{ip}/{port}")
    public Response pingIpPort(@PathParam("ip") String ip, @PathParam("port") String port) {
        String result = null;
        String command = "/tmp/paping -p " + port +" -c 5 " + ip;
        try {
//          ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
//                  "bash", "-c",  "sudo hping3 -S -c 5 -p "+ port + " " + ip );
//          builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
//          Process proc = builder.start();
                        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //              System.out.print(line + "\n");
                LOGGER.warning(line + "\n");
                if(line.contains("Minimum")) {
                    result=line;
                }
            }

            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Read the output
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();     
    }
```

**When I go to the URL mentioned it gave strange encoding like this:**

> Minimum = [01;34m21.46ms[22;0m, Maximum = [01;34m27.20ms[22;0m,
>   Average = [01;34m24.31ms[22;0m

But if I run the command directly from terminal in Ubuntu it will be like this:

> ```
>     Minimum = 20.69ms, Maximum = 28.48ms, Average = 23.77ms
> ```

Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Please share that strange response.

Comment: @EmptyBrain it's the strange encoding as i wrote in the question

Comment: The "strange" encoding (e.g.: `[01;34m`) is caused by [color escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) in bash. Check if that command provides a way to suppress them.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz that's true! I didn't realize it until now. Fortunately the command has nocolor option for it. Thanks